# Section not displayed on browser

Tags: laravel, layout, sections

I am using laravel 6. I have problem with my section where its not display the result on browser. I have place @yield on my layout but half of section still not displayed

here my code

```
@section('main-content')
<section class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h2>Detail Tanaman</h2>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
<!-- ======= Blog Section ======= -->
<section id="blog" class="blog">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-8 entries">

        <article class="entry">

          <div class="entry-img">
            <img src="/img/bonsai.jpg" style ="width:100%; height:100%;" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>

          <h2 class="entry-title">
            {{$data->nama_tanaman}}
          </h2>
```

here my layout

```
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bx bx-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bx bx-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section><!-- End Hero -->

@yield('main-content')
```

Comment: To yield a section then the file that is yielding the section must include a file that contains the section somehow. This is done either using `@include` or if file that has the section is the same file that is also yielding the section. Its not clear here how these two files are related and what you're actually rendering

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add `extends('master')` (master is the name of your master page file) at the first of your section like:

In your master:

```
@yield('main-content')
```

In your section file:

```
@extends('master')
@section('main-content')
    ...
@endsection
```